# Can we integrate SDL Tridion with ATG?

Tags: 2011

I would like to know is there any possibility to integrate SDL Tridion with ATG? I have a business requirement for this kind. If possible please provide the details.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is YES!, but you would need to give a lot more details on what you mean by "integrate". ATG is a complex commerce application, are you trying to use Tridion to manage products? Serve content alongside products? Present products on a Tridion managed site?

I think you get my point. It can be done, but if you have not worked with Tridion before, it would be wise to talk to SDL Professional Services or some other SDL Tridion Architect who has experience designing commerce architectures for enterprise solutions.